# HTML/JavaScript table header

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me to create a new row on top of the table as headers like ..

```
| S.No | Date | Product Name | Client Name |
```

Please look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwBsa/2/)

Comment: Do the same that for the rows but add a [thead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/thead?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fthead) to your table.

Comment: array values are being fetched. I am trying to add a new row on top the table as headers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QwBsa/6/ - ?

Comment: @ZoltanToth: I am going to have a pagination in my page, this is not the approach I am looking for .. Thanks for the code

Comment: You mean fixed header that will stay above even when scrolling the table rows?

Comment: In the question, you need to explain exactly what you want to accomplish. Your descriptions should not be in response to comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var orderArrayHeader = ["S.No", "Date", "Product Name", "Client Name"];
```

...

```
var thead = document.createElement('thead');

table.appendChild(thead);

for (var i=0; i<orderArrayHeader.length; i++) {
    thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
          appendChild(document.createTextNode(orderArrayHeader[i]));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QwBsa/12/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <ht>ClientName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Do some styling and you will get what you want....